Spawn service failed
I`m trying to spawn a urdf model of a robot arm in gazebo and getting this error when I'm launching my launch file.
I have launched some other urdf model they didn't cause much problem.I can't find where i am doing wrong,I have done onshape-to-robot-bullet it is working with this urdf.
I am new in this so can anyone plz tell me what i am doing wrong??
i am getting an error-
FATAL] [1718019695.660225431, 0.226000000]: Package[] does not have a path
[ERROR] [1718019695.660902, 0.226000]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[spawn_urdf-4] process has died [pid 65428, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -x 0.00 -y 0.00 -z 0.00 -Y 0.00 -param robot_description -urdf -model onshape -J base 0.0 -J J1 0.0 -J J2 0.0 -J J3 0.0 -J J4 0.0 -J J5 0.0 -J J7 0.0 -J J8 0.0 __name:=spawn_urdf __log:=/home/puru/.ros/log/222c7472-26f4-11ef-9e10-cdb59c040e69/spawn_urdf-4.log].
log file: /home/puru/.ros/log/222c7472-26f4-11ef-9e10-cdb59c040e69/spawn_urdf-4*.log

here is my launch file
<launch>
   <arg name="arg_x" default="0.00" />
   <arg name="arg_y" default="0.00" />
   <arg name="arg_z" default="0.00" />
   <arg name="arg_R" default="0.00" />
   <arg name="arg_P" default="0.00" />
   <arg name="arg_Y" default="0.00" />


<!--Urdf file path-->
   <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robot_simulation)/robo_hand/robot.urdf"/>
   
   <!--spawn a empty gazebo world-->
   <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch" />
   <node name="tf_footprint_base" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 part1 base_footprint 40" />


   <!--spawn model-->
   <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-x $(arg arg_x) -y $(arg arg_y) -z $(arg arg_z) -Y $(arg arg_Y) -param robot_description -urdf -model onshape -J base 0.0 -J J1 0.0 -J J2 0.0 -J J3 0.0 -J J4 0.0 -J J5 0.0 -J J7 0.0 -J J8 0.0" />


   <!--Load and launch the joint trajectory controller-->
   <rosparam file ="$(find robot_simulation)/config/joint_trajectory_controller.yaml" command="load"/>

   <node name= "controller_spawner" pkg= "controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="joint_state_controller robot_arm_controller hand_ee_controller"/>


   <!-- Robot State Publisher for TF of each joint: publishes all the current states of the joint, then RViz can visualize -->

   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

</launch>

and here is my urdf file
<robot name="onshape">
    
    <link name="world"/>
    
    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="part1"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="part1">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="-3.4694469519536141888e-18 0 0" rpy="0.32265717217483891321 -0.069385932021737206643 -0.011296483062610399029" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package:///part1.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="part1_material">
            <color rgba="0.25098039215686274161 0.25098039215686274161 0.25098039215686274161 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="-3.4694469519536141888e-18 0 0" rpy="0.32265717217483891321 -0.069385932021737206643 -0.011296483062610399029" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package:///part1.stl"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-0.0012805753579643462583 -0.011016660629217271336 0.037515390001028138534" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="7.1875848665246033775" />
        <inertia ixx="0.045297703676770335879" ixy="0.0017840038416941296929"  ixz="-0.0021797906212168887199" iyy="0.048864317605051173221" iyz="-0.011176954156986391997" izz="0.078627058046879902409" />
    </inertial>
</link>

<link name="part2">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="2.4815221297845596725e-18 1.9382986721854770188e-18 0" rpy="-3.141592653589793116 4.6706927436886977151e-17 3.2982806408847512753e-18" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part2.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part2_material">
        <color rgba="0.77647058823529413463 0.7568627450980391913 0.73725490196078435901 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="2.4815221297845596725e-18 1.9382986721854770188e-18 0" rpy="-3.141592653589793116 4.6706927436886977151e-17 3.2982806408847512753e-18" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part2.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.056976512075502590282 0.0027067425703694225278 -0.082849898982706379758" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="2.8798845212323498366" />
    <inertia ixx="0.014881029060141267445" ixy="0.0005744946258076310229"  ixz="-0.01130629902339419339" iyy="0.029629354802626656218" iyz="0.00050369024034264736536" izz="0.020220800009744580722" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part3">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="0 2.7755575615628913511e-17 0" rpy="-3.7506783542939203786e-20 -8.8743673327280038896e-18 7.6013036972471816961e-18" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part3.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part3_material">
        <color rgba="0.25098039215686274161 0.25098039215686274161 0.25098039215686274161 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="0 2.7755575615628913511e-17 0" rpy="-3.7506783542939203786e-20 -8.8743673327280038896e-18 7.6013036972471816961e-18" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part3.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.14018296191340778867 -0.0081202387835428019303 0.015311056033016684844" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.1430996664229595705" />
    <inertia ixx="0.00076194947476914927972" ixy="-0.0002163608373031530223"  ixz="-9.9897566532977007396e-05" iyy="0.021889090949777346984" iyz="-3.8861596724872822018e-05" izz="0.022305318338384585303" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part4">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.049999999999999947264 0.044999999999999928946 -0.048000000000000000999" rpy="-1.570796326794896558 3.3713739677471981044e-18 -2.1095519483509206812e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part4.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part4_material">
        <color rgba="0.79607843137254896693 0.82352941176470584317 0.9372549019607843146 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.049999999999999947264 0.044999999999999928946 -0.048000000000000000999" rpy="-1.570796326794896558 3.3713739677471981044e-18 -2.1095519483509206812e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part4.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.034615093436350663492 0.038537106974319876307 -0.04615997250553626613" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.6158525875678280137" />
    <inertia ixx="0.0022074722855731734351" ixy="-0.00036149006639220559968"  ixz="0.00010291587993125624967" iyy="0.0078248759878263348527" iyz="0.00015452864972509414219" izz="0.0083117281805881355894" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part5">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="3.4694469519536141888e-18 0 0.0050000000000000321965" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part5.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part5_material">
        <color rgba="0.77647058823529413463 0.7568627450980391913 0.73725490196078435901 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="3.4694469519536141888e-18 0 0.0050000000000000321965" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part5.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="2.296209484802755807e-17 1.0429349772845609436e-17 0.07965355910797956851" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.76134524066724451608" />
    <inertia ixx="0.0024657507175976549688" ixy="3.9603891489128208543e-11"  ixz="7.6843053034528262362e-21" iyy="0.0026674883734285675593" iyz="6.3011139360900376271e-20" izz="0.00069980749681859905423" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part6">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.042000000000000037303 -5.5511151231257827021e-17 -1.3877787807814456755e-17" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part6.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part6_material">
        <color rgba="0.77647058823529413463 0.7568627450980391913 0.73725490196078435901 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.042000000000000037303 -5.5511151231257827021e-17 -1.3877787807814456755e-17" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part6.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.059477422323748987965 -5.6643505845066669741e-17 -1.1476450207922689876e-17" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.39696194910041004977" />
    <inertia ixx="0.00027739828305348911098" ixy="1.9884141339072156575e-20"  ixz="3.2463991766502403197e-22" iyy="0.00040803651958911535272" iyz="-2.792385807766648833e-21" izz="0.00041164747096656729725" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part7">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="0 -3.4694469519536141888e-18 0.0099999999999999533706" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part7.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part7_material">
        <color rgba="0.56862745098039213509 0.54901960784313730279 0.50980392156862741615 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="0 -3.4694469519536141888e-18 0.0099999999999999533706" rpy="1.570796326794896558 1.570796326794896558 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part7.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="-1.2926944099447946692e-19 -3.1275151494821297233e-18 -0.0062844669745950390571" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.095529530381998281618" />
    <inertia ixx="4.0005586732361312101e-05" ixy="-2.4656268595522464085e-22"  ixz="1.7806595967162966037e-21" iyy="4.7583367322132944183e-05" iyz="-2.0676986397054393346e-21" izz="5.0210847316137543464e-05" />
</inertial>
</link>

<link name="part9">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.038437349788629754377 0.063553165001418110425 -0.013000000000000684619" rpy="1.570796326794896336 1.5707963267948958919 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part8.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part8_material">
        <color rgba="1 0.96078431372549022438 0.89019607843137249503 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.038437349788629754377 0.063553165001418110425 -0.013000000000000684619" rpy="1.570796326794896336 1.5707963267948958919 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part8.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.01299999999999999073" rpy="-8.829476863248877021e-18 -2.6628065485658611949e-18 -3.5189746478553312204e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part9.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part9_material">
        <color rgba="0.79607843137254896693 0.82352941176470584317 0.9372549019607843146 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.01299999999999999073" rpy="-8.829476863248877021e-18 -2.6628065485658611949e-18 -3.5189746478553312204e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part9.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.019097045128395627456 0.04930456388435456444 -0.013000000000000535433" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.045258281756665255657" />
    <inertia ixx="5.522294637954104575e-05" ixy="-1.4855240157670293133e-05"  ixz="1.5213025994755179093e-19" iyy="7.1527397674249912433e-06" iyz="-2.9789676359037378066e-20" izz="5.9954066756448529444e-05" />
</inertial>
</link>

<joint name="J7" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.040809511095868222785 0.01299999999999999073 -0.022892057511395225156" rpy="-1.570796326794896558 0.10407608628378127447 2.1645097273896630037e-15" />
    <parent link="part7" />
    <child link="part9" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-0.0508254296197560507" upper="1.4854961776254267392"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<link name="part9_2">
<visual>
    <origin xyz="0.038437349788628449865 0.063553165001418443492 0.013000000000001173811" rpy="1.57079632679489678 -1.5707963267948903408 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part8.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part8_material">
        <color rgba="1 0.96078431372549022438 0.89019607843137249503 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="0.038437349788628449865 0.063553165001418443492 0.013000000000001173811" rpy="1.57079632679489678 -1.5707963267948903408 0" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part8.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<visual>
    <origin xyz="-5.5511151231257827021e-17 0 0.012999999999999994199" rpy="1.8669361206154621951e-17 -4.1846222463962295292e-18 -1.1061622554016257027e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part9.stl"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="part9_material">
        <color rgba="0.79607843137254896693 0.82352941176470584317 0.9372549019607843146 1.0"/>
    </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <origin xyz="-5.5511151231257827021e-17 0 0.012999999999999994199" rpy="1.8669361206154621951e-17 -4.1846222463962295292e-18 -1.1061622554016257027e-17" />
    <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package:///part9.stl"/>
    </geometry>
</collision>
<inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.019097045128394322944 0.049304563884354772607 0.013000000000000908398" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.045258281756665255657" />
    <inertia ixx="5.5222946379536119407e-05" ixy="1.485524015766974595e-05"  ixz="6.51183823337792082e-19" iyy="7.1527397674250640881e-06" iyz="1.2029403278356184806e-19" izz="5.9954066756446103541e-05" />
</inertial>
</link>

<joint name="J8" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0.040809511095868222785 -0.013000000000000004607 -0.022892057511395225156" rpy="-1.570796326794896558 -0.10407608628378151039 8.4711537068837356757e-15" />
    <parent link="part7" />
    <child link="part9_2" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-1.4854961776254267392" upper="0.0508254296197560507"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="J5" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.10400000000000086953 -6.6613381477509392425e-16 -1.1171619185290637688e-15" rpy="1.570796326794896558 -2.200659911653516123e-14 1.5707963267948941155" />
    <parent link="part6" />
    <child link="part7" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-6.283185307179586232" upper="6.283185307179586232"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="J4" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-7.0429773124658368033e-16 -1.1102230246251565404e-16 0.13800000000000009481" rpy="1.570796326794896558 8.8953965671821529256e-16 -1.5707963267948921171" />
    <parent link="part5" />
    <child link="part6" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-3.5779249665883754439" upper="0.43633231299858238339"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="J3" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0.22099999999999983546 0.045000000000000928146 -0.047999999999998099742" rpy="3.5360923724163181315e-17 1.5707963267948925612 0" />
    <parent link="part4" />
    <child link="part5" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-3.141592653589793116" upper="3.141592653589793116"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="J2" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.34999999999999981126 -4.7184478546569152968e-16 -1.0408340855860842566e-17" rpy="-7.9084394517820163515e-16 8.181256381192978572e-16 -2.0089744681964760709" />
    <parent link="part3" />
    <child link="part4" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-2.4434609527920612138" upper="1.8849555921538758696"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="J1" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.14999999999999980016 -0.019999999999999993477 -0.16000000000000128009" rpy="-1.570796326794896558 -1.1326181853933210419 3.1415926535897922278" />
    <parent link="part2" />
    <child link="part3" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-2.1745329251994329478" upper="1.3906585039886590671"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="base" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.0058237426852963229684 -0.026571278200745222786 0.079473588039763426449" rpy="3.0684444271150290717 -0.32185277620319291403 1.5826756446767937803" />
    <parent link="part1" />
    <child link="part2" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1" velocity="20" lower="-3.141592653589793116" upper="3.141592653589793116"/>
    <joint_properties friction="0.0"/>
</joint>


<transmission name="link_b_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="base">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_b_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_1_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_1_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_2_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_2_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_3_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J3">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_3_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_4_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J4">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_4_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_5_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J5">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_5_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_7_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J7">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_7_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link_8_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="J8">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="link_8_motor">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part1">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part2">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part3">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part4">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part5">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part6">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part7">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part9">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="part9_2">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>


</robot>


got it! there was a mistake in urdf file,i have given wrong path of the stl file.
